# Need help using preg_match to fix links in articles in database

Tags: php, html, mysql, regex

I have a database of articles that contains about 4,000 broken links in roughly 8,000 articles. About half of these broken links follow a pattern that, with the right PHP script, can be used to automatically fix those broken links.

The broken links in question contain links like this:

```
<a href="http://www.mydomain.tld/article1234-plus-a-slug-
that-varies-in-length.html">some text</a>
```

The "1234" part represents the unique ID of the article. It can be a three to five digit number between 101 and 10700. The database record for that unique ID contains the correct URL for the page.

I need to identify the strings in the HTML of each article that fit this pattern, extract the "1234" part of the URL, assign it to a $variable, and then replace the URL in the HTML markup of the article for that link with the correct URL taken from the database for that unique ID.

I suspect that preg_match is an appropriate function to use in this case, but I really can't see how to build the PHP script. (My PHP skills aren't great. Neither are my regex skills.) Can anyone help me with a simple script to handle this task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$url = '<a href="http://www.mydomain.tld/article1234-plus-a-slug-
that-varies-in-length.html">some text</a>';

preg_match("#article([0-9]+)#i", $url , $urlmatches);

printf( 'id: %d' , (int) $urlmatches[1] );
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, regular expresion seems nice for this challenge.

If these are the only one digits with length from 3 to 5 you can use the following regex:

```
$str = "http://www.mydomain.tld/article1234-plus-a-slug-
that-varies-in-length.html";
preg_match_all('/[0-9]{3,5}/', $str, $matches);
var_dump($matches);
```

`{3,5}` represents the length. So the output here is:

```
array (size=1)
  0 => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => string '1234' (length=4)
```

Answer (score 0):

Is that what you were looking for?

```
$html = '<a href="http://www.mydomain.tld/article1234-plus-a-slug-
that-varies-in-length.html">';
$html = preg_replace('|<a href="[^"]*article(\d+)[^>]*>|', '<a href="htttp://example.com/article.php?id=$1">', $html);
print $html . "\n";
```